# Openresty dynamic spawning of worker process

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

Is is possible to spawn a new worker process and gracefully shutdown an existing one dynamically using Lua scripting in openresty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes but No

Openresty itself doesn't really offer this kind of functionality directly, but it does give you the necessary building blocks:

- nginx workers can be terminated by sending a [signal](https://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html) to them
- openresty allows you to [read the PID](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxworkerpid) of the current wroker thread
- LuaJITs FFI allows you to use the [`kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) system call or
- using `os.execute` you can just call [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) directly.

Combining those, you should be able to achieve what you want :D

---

Note: After reading the question again, I noticed that I really only answered the second part.

`nginx` uses a set number of worker processes, so you can only shut down running workers which the master process will then restart, but the number will stay the same.

If you just want to change the number of worker processes, you would have to restart the nginx instance completely (I just tried `nginx -s reload -g 'worker_processes 4;'` and it didn't actually spawn any additional workers).

However, I can't see a good reason why you'd ever do that. If you need additional threads, there's a separate API for that, other than that, you'll probably just have to live with a hard restart.